# how can i show X + (1/3) images on a fluid layout?

Tags: css

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AtbFR/2.

I have a liquid layout with two columns on either side. The  is 100% with margins for padding and allowing the liquid layout inside the columns.

You can resize the browser to see that more images appear the wider the browser becomes. This is ideal but i need one slight change. It always shows a variable 'X' number of images. I need it to show X+(1/3) images, so if it was a very large window it would show 10 full width images and only 1/3 of the last image.

```
#list {
  width:80%;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#list ul {
  height:40px;
   overflow:hidden;
}

#list ul li {
  display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a min-width on the ul and overflow:hidden on the #list div.

http://jsfiddle.net/AtbFR/3/

```
#list {
  width:80%;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#list ul {
  height:40px;
   overflow:hidden;
  min-width:80px;
}
```

Comment: this appears to do nothing. what browser are you using?